# taking 2 clicks on an option to recognise a click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a custom dropdown. It works perfectly except for when it is the option is clicked for the first time or if an option is clicked after closing the current active option. It takes two clicks to recognise that the option has been clicked. Can anyone help with this?

```js
$(function() {

var currentTab = "";
var lorem1con = "<div id='div1'><ul class='ul-reset'><h6>Heading 1</h6><li><a href='#'>sublink1.1</a></li></ul></div>";
var lorem2con = "<div id='div1'><ul class='ul-reset'><h6>Heading 2</h6><li><a href='#'>sublink2.1</a></li></ul></div>";

$('.navbar-nav>li>span').on("click", function() {

    if (currentTab == "" || currentTab == $(this).html()) {
        $(this).parent().siblings('.mega-menu').css("opacity", "1").stop(true, false, true).slideToggle(300);
    }

    currentTab = $(this).html();
    switch (currentTab) {
        case "Lorem1":
            $('#main-div').empty();
            $('#main-div').append(lorem1con);
            break;
        case "Lorem2":
            $('#main-div').empty();
            $('#main-div').append(lorem2con);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <ul style="list-style: none; padding:0;" class="nav-dropdown navbar-nav">
  <li class='droppable'>
      <span>Lorem1</span>
  </li>
  <li class='droppable'>
      <span>Lorem2</span>
  </li>
  <li class='droppable'>
      <span>Lorem3</span>
  </li>
  <div class='mega-menu'>
      <div class='container cf' id="main-div"></div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

here is my css

```
div.mega-menu {
background: #f0f0f0;
display: none;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
text-align: left;
width: 100%;
max-height: 350px;
}

.mega-menu h3 {
color: #444;
}

.mega-menu ul {
float: left;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-left: 30px;
width: 20%;
padding-left: 0;
list-style: none;
}

.mega-menu ul:last-child {
margin-right: 0;
}

.mega-menu ul li {
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 1;
}

.mega-menu a {
color: #4ea3d8;
display: block;
padding: 5px 0;
}

.mega-menu a:hover {
color: #2d6a91;
}

.container.cf {
padding: 25px 15px;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
/* display: none; */
}

.container.cf>div {
width: 85%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
content: " ";
/* 1 */
display: table;
/* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: add ... .on("click", function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); ... to your click function

Comment: can you put you code example in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem explained

Let's asume that the `div#main-div` is visible, but empty (so invisible for humans).

When you press the `span`, you hide the `div` using `slideToggle` and add the data.

So now your `div` is hidden (first click).

When you click again, the `div` appears (second click).

What you can do, is adding `style="display:none"` to the `div` you toggle (`div.mega-menu`).

Or, you could test this problem by adding some dummy-text in the `div.mega-menu`.

## Possible fixes

Example with dummy-text: https://jsfiddle.net/m9s7vxjL/

Example with display change: https://jsfiddle.net/bwt05783/

Comment: I have already put style="display:none", i'll put my stylesheet too in the question